# How to derive argc from **argv in C

Tags: c

I have an assignment where I'm not allowed to edit the main program, but to free the memory of a copy of argv.  So far the only solution I've found is using argc to determine how many blocks need to be freed.  However, argc is not an input into the freeing program, but a copy of argv is.  Is there anyway to derive argc from **argv?

Comment: How can you create copy of argv then if you don't know argc?

Comment: If you're freeing allocated memory, you probably want to be looking at whatever structure you have that tracks the allocated blocks rather than the length of **argv.

Comment: The last time I made copies of argv, I did it in a single memory block. So freeing it would have been a simple, single free. Of course you cannot edit the original program. But if you could, you'd count all the bytes of all the argv strings including terminating null bytes, plus all the bytes of the argv pointers, allocate that much memory in one malloc, and copy each argv pointer and its contents to the new memory block. It's much more memory efficient than malloc for each string.

Comment: What is the "copy of argv" ? A copy of the list of pointers, of which the "last" one (actually the one after the last relevant one)? Or does the copy also include the "strings" pointed to by those pointer. (Read the answers below and the comments and you will notice that people are unclear about this.) Could you show the part which creates the copy of argv? Could you show the prototype of the function you are supposed to write? Coudl you show how it is called? If you can provide that informaion, then answering your question would be much easier (and lesss downvote-vulnerable...).

Comment: If the only description you received of the `char **` value the function receives is "a copy of `argv`", the problem is horribly underspecified.  You need to know **exactly** how that "copy" was created in order to properly free all the memory allocated for it.  To be pedantic, since C is pass-by-value, even if you pass the original value of `argv` to the function, with the caller making no copies of the data `argv` points to, your function, strictly speaking, receives as its argument "a copy of `argv`", and your function properly needs to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; 1; i++)
        if(argv[i] == 0) break;
        else count++;

    printf("Argc: %d\n", count);
}
```

Or in a compact way (thanks to [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int count;
    for (count = 0; argv[count] != NULL; count++)
        continue;
    printf("Argc: %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: why not simply `for (count = 0; argv[count] != NULL; count++) continue;` ?

Comment: doesn't do whats asked for in the Q

Comment: "Is there anyway to derive argc from **argv?".... I answered this question.